# It is possible to import text from reStructuredText File and put into other file?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have two files engine.rst and car.rst
In the file engine.rst

```
|
Engine
======
V8 Engine with turbo
```

file car.rst

```
.. _Engine: engine.rst
|

Car
======
Ford Mustang

Engine
------
`Engine`_
```

I would like to have the content of engine.rst in car.rst because I need to use engine.rst in several files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the sphinx directive for including a document into another document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880277/what-is-the-sphinx-directive-for-including-a-document-into-another-document)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I could add the text including the other file, but the file had to be .txt to avoid warnings so my code was as follows:

file car.rst

```
|

Car
======
Ford Mustang

Engine
------
.. include:: engine.txt
```